# Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\ is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, windows-server-2008-r2

i wrote a website for someone and want to disable it after two mothns.
(because he should pay for it after two months, if not i should blow it up)
so, i called a DateTime WebService from my web site for getting DateTime.Now!
i should keep web site start time some where in his server and i want to write a text file in C:\Windows\System32.
but when i tried to write a text file in this path, i got the error below :

```
Access to the path 'C:\Windows\System32\ is denied.
```

at this time i have remote access to his server and can change permissions.
but if he change his server, he will see that error and can find that file and edit it easily.
would you please learn me a way for fix that error or another way for saving web site start time!(mean where?)
database is not a good idea, because he has access to his database.
i can write that file on c drive and change it's attributes (hidden and system), but he can find this file easily.

would be appreciate for some help

Comment: You need to trust your client a little more.

Comment: i do n't know what is going on in my area.but some people do n't respect WebDevelopers.

Comment: If the user has administrative access to the server, there's no way you can stop him.  You'll have to trust that he's honest and won't circumvent your time limit.

Comment: It is rarely ever a good idea to store application specific files in Windows' System32 directory. If you absolutely must do it this way consider using the registry or somewhere within your sandbox.

Comment: Would it not be easier to avoid writing there in the first place? You don't need to log the web site start time, since you're the one who put it there: you already know exactly when it is. Your website can check the server date, and if it's 17 Feb 2012 or later, refuse to run. You're not managing the server, so don't mess with the server if you don't have to.

Comment: Don't write anything to that folder. It's owned by Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking to start a "cat and mouse" game, and whatever you attempt, someone will find a way around it.  Additionally, any attempts you make to limit the availability of the website will likely result in bugs around the licensing code, etc.

I strongly encourage you to consider an alternate approach.  Don't attempt to make any limitations through technical means.  Web sites require support.  Provide a ongoing support contract.  If your client stops paying, he may still have the website, but no one to support it.

Otherwise, another option to consider is that your hosting model is wrong.  Host the website for your client, and then the hosting contains the expense.  It would also eliminate any technical issues with your client trying to circumvent any licensing controls you add - assuming that your client doesn't have access to your web host.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your client does not have access to the sources, why not simply add Google Analytics and you will see how/when it is being used....

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea that you may create a Web Service, call that Web Service from your code behind and that Web Service is being run by you on any other online server. 
The purpose of this Web Service will be that it will check the Name of the Customer/Client and after that there can be a custom-made XML File or Text file  which will search that this specific client is given the access to continue using the Application or not.

And if you want some authentication etc. you may use authentication too in that Web Service. 
I think you may use Microsoft WCF Services too for that reason.

This Web Service will be re-usable to other clients and other projects too.